# Testing MassTransit Subsciber

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, masstransit

I need to test my subscriber which is using MassTransit.

Below is a sample code :

```
using System;
using MassTransit;

public class AnimalSubscriber : Consumes<Animal>.Context
{
    public void Consume(IConsumeContext<Animal> message)
    {
        //.. my code here..
    }
}
```

Right now I have not Idea how to test the Subscriber. If someone could let me know some details; that would be very helpful!

As of now, foolishly I thought of creating a Object of AnimalSubscriber and call the Consume method.

```
[TestFixture]
public class Test
{
    [Test]
    public void SearchAnimals()
    {
        AnimalSubscriber subscriber = new AnimalSubscriber();
        Animal request = new Animal
        {
            Id : 1,
            Name : "Tiger"
        };

        //Not sure how to mock this IReceiveContext.
        IReceiveContext context = new ReceiveContext();

        IConsumeContext<Animal> message =new ConsumeContext<Animal>(context, request); 

        subscriber.Consume(null);
    }
}
```

But I got stuck with the below line of code :

```
IConsumeContext<Animal> message =new ConsumeContext<Animal>(context, request); //<- Not sure how to mock this IReceiveContext.
```

> Error : The type 'MassTransit.Context.ReceiveContext' has no
>   constructors defined

Need some advice please!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MassTransit v2 (which based on the interfaces you've specified above is indeed the case), you can use the `Testing` namespace to build out your tests.

An example unit test is available in the v2 repository branch: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/v2-master/src/MassTransit.Tests/Testing/ConsumerTest_Specs.cs#L19

As an example, a testing fixture can be setup to build your consumer and send messages to it:

```
_test = TestFactory.ForConsumer<AnimalSubscriber>()
    .InSingleBusScenario()
    .New(x =>
        {
            x.ConstructUsing(() => new AnimalSubscriber());

            x.Send(new Animal(), (scenario, context) => context.SendResponseTo(scenario.Bus));
        });

_test.Execute();
```

Then you can build assertions around that test, such as:

```
_test.Sent.Any<A>().ShouldBeTrue();
```

Note that this only works with v2, the Testing namespace, while present in v3, doesn't exactly work yet (it didn't survive the move to `async` and I haven't taken the time to get it entirely working yet).